# Embed Android emulator in .NET application

Tags: c#, android, android-emulator

I am developing a survey designer application in .NET C# which exports the surveys to a file which is sent to android devices. The android device will parse the survey file and show it in the survey mobile app.

Now, I want the user to be able to preview in the .NET application, so they can have an idea of how the survey will look in the android device by displaying the application in an android emulator. Furthermore, I want the emulator to be shown inside a windows form or panel.

My question is: **is it possible to show the android emulator inside a winform application and is it possible to communicate with it? In other words, is there any APIs or extensions for Android Emulator in .NET framework?**

I have searched the internet for the topic but most results talk about communicating with the emulator via **TCP** port and launching the application by creating a new process in the .NET app.

It is important to me to be able to display the emulator inside my application since I do not want to deploy multiple applications to my clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a Hyper-V instance programmatically using its [WMI provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The Hyper-V instance can run without visible window to the user, and you can send [mouse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) clicks & [keyboard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) input, then take a [screenshot](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylorb/2008/07/29/hyper-v-wmi-creating-a-thumbnail-image/).

**But**, it seems to be infinitely easier and lighter to just replicate the layout logic from the Android app in your C# app. If you went with the Android Emulator route, you're hosting a minimum 512 MB process and all the CPU & GPU usage involved.